# Can this be done as a SQL VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-view, having-clause

I have a SQL Server table of Customer's Events:

```
CREATE TABLE CustomerEvent
(
    CustomerID int,
    EventType int,
    EventDate datetime
)
```

There can be many EventTypes for the same customer in one day.

EventTypes are like

1 - CheckIn
2 - CheckOut
3 - ExamStart
4 - ExamEnd

Now I want to select Customers that are currently (today) on premises. That's Clients who had checked in, but hadn't checked out, no matter if they taking Exam currently or not. Can this be done as a SQL view, or do I have to write a stored procedure for that?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Can customers enter on one day and exit on another?

Comment: @GordonLinoff no, they can't, checkout happens same day for all

Comment: @GMB added the tag and updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want today.  So I would suggest `not exists`:

```
select ce.customerid
from customerevent ce
where eventtype = 1 and
      event_date >= current_date and
      event_date < current_date + interval '1 day' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from customerevent ce2
                  where ce2.customerid = ce.customerid and
                        ce2.eventtype = 2 and
                        ce2.eventdate > ce.eventdate
                 );
```

You can easily incorporate this into a view.

Note:  date/time functions are notoriously database specific, so the exact syntax for "today" may vary.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, this can be written as:

```
select ce.customerid
from customerevent ce
where eventtype = 1 and
      convert(date, event_date) >= concat(date, current_date) and
      not exists (select 1
                  from customerevent ce2
                  where ce2.customerid = ce.customerid and
                        ce2.eventtype = 2 and
                        ce2.eventdate > ce.eventdate
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation, and filter with a `having` clause that compares the last check in of each customer to their last check out:

```
create view customerview as
select customerid
from customerevent
group by customerid
having 
    max(case when eventtype = 1 then eventdate end) 
        > max(case when eventtype = 2 then eventdate end)
    or (
        max(case when eventtype = 1 then eventdate end) is not null
        and max(case when eventtype = 2 then eventdate end) is null
    )
```

The second condition in the `having` condition handles customers that checked in at least once but never checked out.

We can simplify the query a little with `coalesce()` and a fixed date that you are sure to be prior to any row in your table:

```
having max(case when eventtype = 1 then eventdate end) 
    > max(case when eventtype = 2 then eventdate else '19700101' end)
```